# How to save data as an object with AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, state, asyncstorage

I'm trying to save some basic user info (name, address, phone number, etc.) with AsyncStorage.

I want to store this information in an object like so:

```
  user: {
            complete: '',
            fname: '',
            lname: '',
            email: '',
            phone: '',
            street: '',
            city: '',
            state: '',
            zip: '',
            phone: ''
        }
```

I have a simple page with a textbox and a button to test this out. the textbox will be for inputting the "fname" value of my user object, and the button just submits it to asyncStorage:

```
export default class UserInfo extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: "Coming soon!"
    };
    state = {
        user: {
            complete: '',
            fname: '',
            lname: '',
            email: '',
            phone: '',
            street: '',
            city: '',
            state: '',
            zip: '',
            phone: ''
        },
        isLoading: true
    }
    componentDidMount = () => AsyncStorage.getItem('user').then((value) => this.setState({ 'user': value, isLoading: false}))
    setUser = (value) => {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('user', value);
     }
    render() {
        if(this.state.isLoading) {
            return (<ActivityIndicator/>)
        }
        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput
                        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
                        onChangeText={(text) => this.state.user.fname}/>
                <Button title="submit" onPress = {() => {this.setUser(this.state.user)}}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I seem to get snagged on this line:

```
onChangeText={(text) => this.state.user.fname}/>
```

I get the following error:
`null is not an object (evaluating '_this2.state.user.fname')`

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here, I had no issue storing simple strings in asyncStorage, but trying to write to an object in state is giving me trouble.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to change to strign before you set them in AsyncStorage.  Use this 
to set `AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.state.user))` 
and this to get `const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user')` and then `this.setState({ user: JSON.parse(user) })`

Comment: @sinan this makes sense, however making this change has no effect on the error. I think it's because the actual assignment of this.state.user inside of my textfield onChange()

Answer (score 1):

Use it as:

```
export default class UserInfo extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: "Coming soon!"
    };
    state = {
        user: {
            complete: '',
            fname: '',
            lname: '',
            email: '',
            phone: '',
            street: '',
            city: '',
            state: '',
            zip: '',
            phone: ''
        },
        isLoading: true
    }
    componentDidMount = () => AsyncStorage.getItem('user').then((value) => this.setState({ 'user': value, isLoading: false}))
    setUser = () => {
        this.setState({user:this.state.user},()=>{
          AsyncStorage.setItem('user', this.state.user);
        })
     }
    render() {
        if(this.state.isLoading) {
            return (<ActivityIndicator/>)
        }
        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput
                        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
                        onChangeText={(text) => this.state.user.fname}/>
                <Button title="submit" onPress = {() => {this.setUser()}}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution and I'm getting the exact same issue. I think the problem lies somewhere else other than the setUser() function, especially since that's not where my error is pointing

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly update the state as you code. You need to grab the object from state, then update its value and then you store object into state again. Below is the correct answer:

```
onChangeText={(text) => {
   let user = this.state.user
    user.fname = text
    this.setState({
        user
     })
}}/>
```

Comment: This is something that I tried earlier, and I get the same result. I get a nullpointer on "user.fname = text". Not sure why